# How can I remove the white background from a profile picture?

Tags: macos, graphics, user-account

I want to set a profile picture that has a transparent background, but when I do it gets a white circle in the background that I do not want. Is there a way to prevent this from happening, or maybe just set the alpha value of the colour it uses?

[image]

The original image does not have the outer white circle.

Comment: Against what background do you want to match colors? Alpha makes a color transparent and masks the image so that any background can show through. Do you have keynote or any software like Photoshop or equivalent?

Comment: The original image already has a transparent background, but when it is set as the user picture the outer white circle in the example is added by osx.

Comment: So you're looking to modify the crop algorithm in system preferences? (or the log in screen where you pick a user to log in to start the window server and GUI processes?)

Comment: I guess it'll be in the crop process, since the modified image is used in the users list in Preferences->Users as well as on the login screen.